Is $\text{logCLIQUE}\in \texttt{NSPACE($\log^2(n)$)}$?
I inspired by this question, $$\text{logCLIQUE}=\{\langle G\rangle:\text{G=(V,E) contains a clique of size $\log(|V|)$}\}.$$
Here $G$ is an undirected graph and it can be assumed that the number of its vertices is a power of $2$.
How  to prove that $\text{logCLIQUE}\in \texttt{NSPACE($\log^2(n)$)}?$
My intuition is, We can nondeterministically guess a set of $\log(|V|)$ vertices and verify if they form a clique by checking all $\binom{\log(|V|)}{2}$ edges between the guessed vertices. This requires storing the guessed vertices and performing adjacency checks, both of which can be done in $O(\log^2(|V|))$ space, placing the problem in $\texttt{NSPACE($\log^2(n)$)}$.
There maybe the problem with the my approach is that it incorrectly assumes $\binom{\log(|V|)}{2}$ adjacency checks can be done in $O(\log^2(|V|))$ space, but each adjacency check might need $\log(|V|)$ space, making the total space potentially exceed $O(\log^2(n))$.
I have one more confusion from it is that : is there exists a deterministic Turing machine that uses $O(\log^4(n))$ memory and solves $\text{logCLIQUE}$?

Why would each adjacency check need $\log\left(\lvert V \rvert\right)$ space? I don’t follow that part.

@wobtax Each adjacency check might need $\log(|V|)$ space because to check if an edge exists between two vertices, we need to store and reference the vertex indices, which each require $\log(|V|)$ bits. Storing and checking pairs of vertices might thus take up more space than initially estimated.

I think this depends on the data structure. What if you make an adjacency table of the subgraph induced by your choice of $\log\left(\lvert V\rvert\right)$ vertices, then check if all the entries are $1$?

@wobtax Using an adjacency table for the induced subgraph would still require $\log^2(|V|)$ space, as the table has $\binom{\log(|V|)}{2}$ entries and storing the vertex indices would require $\log(|V|)$ bits each. This approach does not reduce the space complexity below $\texttt{NSPACE}(\log^2(n))$.

@wobtax would you explain your opinion? Is there any way to prove this?

Here's how I'm seeing it: the table has ${\log\left(\lvert V\rvert\right)\choose 2}$ entries, each of which is a 1 (this edge exists) or a 0 (this edge doesn't exist). You also write down, in order, the indices of the vertices you've chosen—and this ordering is enough information to look up the entries in the table. Is that what you're imagining?

@wobtax Yes, I am thinking in this way.

@wobtax would you kindly, accumulated all your comments and put it as an answer?

Sure, I'm happy to!

Your intuition is right
You can perform all the adjacency checks within $O\!\left(\log^2\left(\lvert V\rvert\right)\right)$ space.

Nondeterministically choose $\log(\lvert V\rvert)$ vertices and write their indices down on the tape, with a separator character. (This takes $O\!\left(\log^2\left(\lvert V\rvert\right)\right)$ cells.)
Write an adjacency matrix of size $\log^2\left(\lvert V\rvert\right)$ for the subgraph induced by the chosen vertices, where the $(i,j)$th cell is

$1$ if vertex $i$ and vertex $j$ share an edge (or if $i=j$),
$0$ otherwise.


Check if the adjacency matrix contains a $0$.

The space used is still $O\!\left(\log^2\left(\lvert V\rvert\right)+\log^2\left(\lvert V\rvert\right)\right) = O\!\left(\log^2\left(\lvert V\rvert\right)\right)$.
Neither of the above steps is optimal: they can both be modified to use even less space. But it will be easier to write the Turing machine this way.
Is there a deterministic version in $O\!\left(\log^4\left(\lvert V\rvert\right)\right)$ space?
Yes, by Savitch's Theorem.

Would you check my Savitch theorem for last part of the question.

By Savitch's theorem, any problem solvable in nondeterministic space  $S(n)$ can also be solved deterministically in space $O(S(n)^2) $. Since finding a clique of size $\log(n)$  can be done using nondeterministic  $O(\log^2(n))$ space (guessing the vertices of the clique and verifying in log space), Savitch's theorem implies that there exists a deterministic algorithm that solves the problem in $O((\log^2(n))^2) = O(\log^4(n)) $ space. Hence, logCLIQUE can be solved by a deterministic Turing machine using $O(\log^4(n)) $ space.

Would tell me, am I correct?

You can do it in deterministic space $O(\log^2n)$: instead of guessing the clique nondeterministically, systematically enumerate all $(\log n)$-tuples of vertices. Also, there is no point whatsoever in writing down the new adjacency matrix, as you are never going to use the entries again. Just look up all pairs of the chosen vertices one after another in the big adjacency matrix, and stop once you find a missing edge. This check only needs $O(\log n)$ space.
